# Processing 2500 rows in Mule ESB?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, mule, esb, mule-component

Some times mule jdbc:inbound-endpoint is selecting 2500 rows from a view (witch is having joins with 8 different tables) per hour and processing long time(15 to 20 minutes).
While processing the selected rows is it block or lock the tables which are used in this view? Would these long running job leads to any issues?

```
<jdbc:inbound-endpoint queryKey="SelectQ" connector-ref="QConnector" doc:name="FromView" pollingFrequency="3600000" queryTimeout="-1" exchange-pattern="one-way"> <jdbc:transaction action="NONE"></jdbc:transaction> <jdbc:query key="SelectQ" value="select * from view_name where processed =0"></jdbc:query> </jdbc:inbound-endpoint>
```

Comment: What is your setup exactly? code? some details to go on?

Comment: jdbc:inbound-endpoint polling frequency is one hour. Here it used to select  the rows from a view and process them.

Comment: <jdbc:inbound-endpoint queryKey="SelectQ"
                  connector-ref="QConnector" doc:name="FromView"
                  pollingFrequency="3600000" queryTimeout="-1"
                  exchange-pattern="one-way">
                  <jdbc:transaction action="NONE"></jdbc:transaction>
                  <jdbc:query key="SelectQ" value="select * from view_name where processed =0"></jdbc:query>
            </jdbc:inbound-endpoint>

Comment: Please edit this information (and also any other relevant information) into the question.

Comment: Please let me know what information do you want ? I will try to provide that

Comment: This question is too open. Also locking will depend on the specific database implementation. Does it block when you perform a similar query from another JDBC client? Mule doesn't know it is a table or a view.